# Why is the name appearing empty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am new to React and I am trying to use state for the first time. For some reason `statelist.name` does not return anything. Do I need to use a constructor ? Any Help would be great.

```
import React from 'react';

class HorizantScroller extends React.Component {

  state = {
    statelist: [
  {name: "Brands",
    items: ["1", "2", "3"]
  },
  {name: "Films",
    items: ["f1", "f2", "f3"]
  },
  {name: "Holiday Destination",
    items: ["f1", "f2", "f3"]
  }
]

  };

  render() {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    // Create menu from items
    const menu = Menu(list, selected);
    const {statelist} = this.state;


    return (
      <div>
      <div name={statelist.name}></div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default HorizantScroller;
```

Comment: `statelist` is an array, not an object. You have to tell it what object to access the property on. To test try `statelist[0].name`.

Comment: ok so how about if i want to access all the names of ```statelist``` not just the first item ?

Comment: The [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 2):

StateList is an array, you will need to specify the index of the state first and the get the property 'name'. Example: statelist[0].name

Comment: ok so how about if i want to access all the names of statelist not just the first item ?

Comment: Then you will need to use some array iterator function like foreach or [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This way you will loop through the array and perform the actions you need. If you want you can create a new array just with the names using
const names = statelist.map(state => state.map);
This way you can loop through this new array without having to worry about the properties

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this to make it dynamic:

```
{statelist.map((list,index)=>{
   return (
        <div key={index} name={list.name}></div>
     );
})

}
```

This way you would have all the values in the statelist. replace the `<div name={statelist.name}></div>` with the above code.
Notice how i have added a `key` to the div. this is important for react to distinguish between the divs and also it'll complain in the console if you don't do it :).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with the react state, is with the data types you're using. First of all `statelist` is not an object so you can't use `statelist.name`, it's an array so you need to pass an index of the position of the array you're trying to retrieve, it should be something like `statelist[0].name`.

If you want to access all the names of statelist not just the first item you need iterate in the array and do something like this:

```
{statelist.map((element,index) => (
   <div key={index} name={element.name}></div>
 )) }
```

Answer (score 0):

`statelist` is an array and does not have a field named `name`. The elements of the array has the field `name`. This means you have to access an element. You can do this with an index:

```js
let index = 0;

<div name={statelist[0].name}></div>
```

If you want to get the names of all elements you can use the `map` function:

```js
{statelist.map(element => {
  return (
    <div name={element.name}></div>
  );
})}
```